# UID attribute is missing from the subject after that the certificate signing request is signed

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, ca, subject, uid

I have a certificate signing request generated with this command:

```
openssl req -config extensions -new -newkey rsa:4092 -nodes -keyout certificate.key -out certificate.csr
```

The extensions file contains these fields (among other)

```
[req_distinguished_name ]
UID = ABC1234
CN = MyCertificateCN
```

If I dump the csr subject I get:

```
openssl req -noout -subject -in certificate.csr

subject=/UID=ABC1234/CN=MyCertificateCN
```

Then I sign my request using my internal CA:

```
openssl ca -out signed_certificate.pem -infiles certificate.csr
```

However when I dump the signed certificate the UID field is missing:

```
openssl x509 -noout -subject -in signed_certificate.pem

subject=/CN=MyCertificateCN
```

Why is this happening ? Do I need to configure something in the CA ?
I also tried to override the subject in the `openssl ca` command by providing the `subj` option but the **UID** attribute is not kept. Passing `-config extensions` in in the `openssl ca` command didn't help either.

Comment: Ok but if the UID wasn't recognized this wouldn't have been appeared in the CSR. Note that if I create a self-signed certificate using the same extension file the UID attribute is present. So it seems like that the signature process remove it for some reason.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk This is the OID for the UID atrtibute: 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19341-01/817-5235/attribut.html

Comment: In the default config file (since you didn't specify another) in the `[ca]` section get the value of `default_ca`, in the section with that name get `policy`, and in _that_ section see the OID-names; _only_ those go in Subject DN of the new cert unless you specify `-preserveDN`, see [the man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ca.html#POLICY-FORMAT). @PresidentJamesK.Polk this UID is userid not unique-id, and is known in OpenSSL. This is not programming or development.

Comment: "Multi-valued RDNs can be formed by placing a `+` character instead of a `/` between the AttributeValueAssertions (AVAs) that specify the members of the set. Example: `/DC=org/DC=OpenSSL/DC=users/UID=123456+CN=John Doe`" [Source](https://beta.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-req.html#subj-arg)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the correct steps to keep the UID attribute:

##### 1)

Open the file **/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf** and add these lines
    
[ new_oids ]
...
**UID=0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1**
...
[ policy_match ]
...
**UID                     = optional**
...
[ policy_anything ]
...
**UID                     = optional**
...

##### 2)

In the `openssl req` command add the option `-subj "/UID=ABC1234+CN=MyCertificateCN"` and `-multivalue-rdn`:

`openssl req -subj "/UID=ABC1234+CN=MyCertificateCN -multivalue-rdn -config extensions -new -newkey rsa:4092 -nodes -keyout certificate.key -out certificate.csr`

##### 3)

In the `openssl ca` command add `-subj "/UID=ABC1234+CN=MyCertificateCN"` and `-multivalue-rdn` and `-preserveDN` and if you want to keep also the extensions `-extfile extensions` (same file passed in the `openssl req` command with `-config`)

`openssl ca -subj "/UID=ABC1234+CN=MyCertificateCN -multivalue-rdn -preserveDN -extfile extensions -out signed_certificate.pem -infiles certificate.csr`

In this way both the UID attribute and the extensions are kept during the signing process.